# Automate meta tagging of OCR-ed documents

Tags: file-metadata

I was wondering if I could scan a paper document with an OCR software and then meta tag the document accordingly with certain content within the document. Can this process be automated?

Thanks,
Swastik

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own custom code, this can be automated. Options might be:

- Built a list event receiver to extract the content and built some logic on that.
- Get the metadata before uploading the document and set the metadata on adding the document to your library.

You have to be more specific in what you are trying to achieve to get more concrete answers.It all depends on your document flow and the tools you are already using.

Have you tried to search on "scan ocr to SharePoint". There are pretty good products available form vendors like Abby and IRIS that might do what you are looking for.